Should I use a PIC24EP128MC202 or PIC10F200 for input detection?
I want to know if I can use either one of them (or both) to detect an input from a pin and according to that, set an output to another pin (or to the same pin - optional.) I made an attempt to program the PIC10F200 (the code is down below) but I saw the PIC24EP128MC202 has analog to digital converter and I questioned the potential of PIC10F200. I have minimum knowledge on programming overall and even less about embedded.
The code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <PIC10F200.h>

// CONFIG
#pragma config WDTE = OFF 
#pragma config CP = OFF 
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF
// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main() {
    while (1) 
    {
        TRISGPIO = 0b00000010;
        GPIO = 0b00000000;
        if (GPIObits.GP1 == 1)
            GPIObits.GP0 = 1;
        else
            GPIObits.GP1 = 0;
     }
} 


I thought adding microchips related question here would be good, since Stackoverflow wasn't so friendly towards electrical and embedded programming with me. Also  I though it was inclined to coding since arduino is pretty much a microchip with a bunch of other extra "goodies", but it's more expensive to purchase one of those compared to a microcontroller dedicated just to light up 3LED with 1 button. I lack knowledge but I know this is a path to mid-maxing electronics.

detect an input from a pin and according to that, set an output to another pin ... you can use a piece of wire for that, no microcontroller required

Using MCU for this is a bit weird. Can you explain what do you intend to do and why would a MCU work to do it? Even more so since you say you want to detect something on input and even output it again on same pin.

@Justme , I can use the 3pins output to give a certain color(RGB LED band) from a button in command, and than just swap the colors, use cases to do that. This is an example for my usage

@Ihavenoenemies That's fine but you don't need a microcontroller for that.

@Justme eyeballing the certain voltage input for each pin would be hard but I think your suggestion to rethink the idea would be wise to take into account.

Either MCU will do this just fine. Pretty much any MCU will do this just fine. Most likely, you can achieve what you want with some logic gates or transistors or, as mentioned in a comment by @jsotola, a wire as well, depending on your actual input and output configuration.
I'd suggest you find the MCU that you can get easily in a ready to use form. Arduino is a good ecosystem for that kind of thing, for example. Pick something that's within your cost tolerance and comes with everything you need to get started. Trying to get a toolchain and programmer working can be daunting if you pick the wrong chip, so if you already have PIC tooling or people around you comfortable with the PIC ecosystem, use that. The MCU option might seem cheaper, but the costs associated with board bring up for a novice can be exponentially larger than the cost of a ready solution like the arduino (unless you're planning for large volume production)
.
Even as someone who has used AVRs since long before arduino existed, and who's never really warmed up the Arduino ecosystem, when I needed an MCU for a quick and dirty setup a month ago I just purchased an Arduino nano instead of spending an afternoon hunting for parts and soldering.
As an aside, while Microchip does own AVR now, arduino is a different ecosystem. I do not know how much of the community has accepted the microchip purchase, and at any rate, to lump PICs in with Arduinos is probably not going to be very helpful.
